# split string after 2nd character occurence

Tags: python, split

This is my string `70354871699YG000_7798419T0000_1`.

I want to get the first part of while disregarding anything that comes after the 2nd underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to spilit all occurences of '_' and join the first two parts thogether like

```
string = "70354871699YG000_7798419T0000_1"
splits = re.split(r"_",string)

"_".join(splits[:2])
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the 'r' do in the split?

Comment: its just raw string so you dont have to escape special characters probably not needed

Answer (score 1):

You could match the first underscore using a negated character `[^_]` class first matching any char except `_` and then match `_`

Assert the second underscore using a positive lookahead:

```
^[^_]+_[^_]+(?=_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZyYin/1)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this using python I would suggest:

```
string = "70354871699YG000_7798419T0000_1"
string = string.split("_",2)
string = string[2]
```

Not the best code, but hey it works.